# Initialize an array inside of a struct (w/ and array of values)

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Is it possible to initialize an array with values inside of a structure in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    int student_number[2];
    };

int main(void){

    struct student {
        int student_number = {35434, 56343};
    }

    struct student example_student;

    printf("%i \n", example_student.student_number[0]);


    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Thanks, Eric P, this cleared this up some of the confusion I was having with other examples I came across.

Edit of the above code to show fix:

```
struct student{
    int student_number[2];
};

int main(void){

    struct student example_student = {
        .student_number = {35434, 56343}
    };

    printf("%i \n", example_student.student_number[0]);
```

Comment: What does your compiler say about it?

Comment: @EOF: Their compiler says that way is not valid, but it does not answer the question of whether it is possible, using some other syntax.

Comment: I'm aware that this is not a functioning code example. This was more an for explaining the question.

 `error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
         int student_number = {35434, 56343};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize a structure object when you define it, and that includes initializing an array member inside the structure:

```
struct student example_student = { { 35434, 56343 } };
```

You can also specifically identify the structure member you want to initialize:

```
struct student example_student = { .student_number = { 35434, 56343 } };
```